# Aptitude to learn proprietary systems/applications quickly and easily

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrase-requests, sentence

Updating my resume and I am trying to make this "resume highlight" make sense.  I originally had it written as "Able to learn proprietary systems/applications quickly and easily" but I was looking for a better word first or rewritten sentence.  I was researching this word/sentence using "Google search" and that is where I found you.  The Aptitude word was found on this website but I don't think it makes sense, but I need a word that looks good on a resume.

Comment: This is the English StackExchange and not the Workplace StackExchange, but some advice nonetheless: that sentence by itself is meaningless, no matter how perfect a word you find. Instead of generic sugar-coating, use concrete examples. What proprietary systems have you worked with? How quickly did you learn them?

Comment: @KevinWorkman This claim doesn't preclude listing past accomplishments, and I expect he already does. This is describing a general quality he believes he possesses that would be valuable to employers. He's just looking for the best way to express it, which is a reasonable use of this site.

Comment: I happen to think that the existing wording is fine, you don't have to use long words just to sound more "professional".

Comment: Youse guys are both right - (a) the sentence is crap but (b) there's nothing wrong with some filler here and there  :-)  What about **I learn new development extremely quickly. I learn new APIs extremely quickly. I learn new proprietary system extremely quickly. I am very experienced in kicking-ass.**

Comment: @Barmar thank you for your decorum and your response to my question.

Answer (score 1):

**Fast learner** or **Quick learner** are common expressions, and either one fits here.

For example:

Fast learner of proprietary systems and applications:

- At company FOO, became lead supporter of there QUX management system after first month
- At company BAR, rewrote all system documentation of their BAZ product during first six months
- ...

Comment: Yeah, I have something like that on my resume.